# typescript module resolution not working when trying to debug on vscode

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to debug a module that we have in our project, but since we moved to a different directory structure I am having a hard time attaching the debugger on vscode.

I have the following tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true /* Enable importing .json files. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@common": ["common"],
      "@common/*": ["common/*"]
    },

    "allowJs": false,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "noImplicitAny": true /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied any type. */,
    "strictNullChecks": true /* Enable strict null checks. */,
    "noImplicitThis": true /* Raise error on this expressions with an implied any type. */,
    "alwaysStrict": true /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

When I try to lunch the debugging with the following configuration:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "module-a Debug",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/module-a/index.ts",
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/module-a/**/*.js", "${workspaceFolder}/dist/common/**/*.js"],
      "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
    },
  ]
}
```

I get the following error:
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught Error Error: Cannot find module '@common'

I looked at trace of tsc and it seems like it found the module during resolution

```
Module name '@common', matched pattern '@common'.
Trying substitution 'common', candidate module location: 'common'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location 'project/src/common', target file types: TypeScript, Declaration.
File 'project/src/common.ts' does not exist.
File 'project/src/common.tsx' does not exist.
File 'project/src/common.d.ts' does not exist.
File 'project/src/common/package.json' does not exist according to earlier cached lookups.
File 'project/src/common/index.ts' exists - use it as a name resolution result.
======== Module name '@common' was successfully resolved to 'project/src/common/index.ts'. ========
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "proj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "proj",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.ts",
    "test": "npm run test:unit && npm run test:integration",
    "test:unit": "jest --config jest.config.js",
    "test:integration": "jest --config jest.integration.config.js",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chevrotain": "^10.5.0",
    "commander": "^11.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "js-yaml": "^4.1.0",
    "kysely": "^0.26.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "pg": "^8.11.1",
    "sql-formatter": "^12.2.4",
    "winston": "^3.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/commander": "^2.12.2",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/js-yaml": "^4.0.5",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.195",
    "@types/node": "^20.5.0",
    "@types/pg": "^8.10.2",
    "@types/winston": "^2.4.4",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

In the transpiled files I see
`require("@common")`

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was the following:

1. installing tsconfig-paths

`npm install tsconfig-paths`

2. Adding this to the vscode configuration

`"runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register"]`

1. To make things works using `npm run`  it was required adding

```
"ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
```

to the tsconfig